# Can you have the same website with a different tld(.com, .uk, ...) from different hosts while only hosting on one host?

Tags: url, web-hosting, tld

I've bought a domain from godaddy (no webhosting), and want to buy another domain with the same name, just a different tld (ones .de, the other .com).

Is it possible to host on only one provider, but have both .de and .com lead to the same page.

Comment: This question would be more appropriate for http://serverfault.com.  But the answer is "Yes".  You can assign as many different DNS hostnames as you want to a given IP address.

Comment: Ouh sorry! I'm quite new here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do this.

From the cpannel you will click on addon domain and will add the seocnd domain there and then will set the location for the files of website then at that location on server you can place your second site